# Is a Plasmoid's Shape Self similar to a Changeling's Mask?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, shapeshifting

The [Plasmoid's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1121698-plasmoid) Shape Self states:

> As an action, you can reshape your body to give yourself a head, one
> or two arms, one or two legs, and makeshift hands and feet, or you can
> revert to a limbless blob. While you have a humanlike shape, you can
> wear clothing and armor made for a Humanoid of your size.

What confuses me is how much details the creature's "human-like" appearance can have... is it still an amorphous form, like Batman's Clayface? Is it a colloidal molded human like an anime slime girl or gummy bear? Or might it have the ability to render a detailed humanoid shape like a changeling's mask or the T-1000?

I might have missed the part where it clarifies, but from the artwork and use of words like "makeshift" and "humanlike," I'd suspect that it would gain the appearance of a humanoid only in the loosest sense of the word. Yet reading that it can wear all humanoid clothing and armour (including form-fitting full plate, necklaces, hats, masks, chokers, gloves, etc.), it sounds much more detailed...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No, they are not able to assume likeness of another race

The description of the plasmoid race opens with:

> Plasmoids are amorphous beings with no typical shape. In the presence of other folk, they often adopt a similar shape, **but there’s little chance of mistaking a plasmoid for anything else.**

Compare this to the Changeling description which states:

> You can **make yourself appear as a member of another race**, though none of your game statistics change.

Combine this with [their depiction](https://www.nerdsandscoundrels.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/plasmoid-5e.jpg), and it is translucently clear that they look like deformed blobs with fine enough splitting of limbs and fingerlike protusions that they can wear armor and clothing — like those shown on the example image.

Comment: What still confuses me is how would the depiction wear something that's made for an actual "humanoid their size" and not just the vague shape of one, like a sallet helmet (that requires a chin and neck). I understand that they cannot change their colour to fully pass off as a humanoid, but would their ability be good enough to gain, say, defined cheekbones, eye sockets, and a jaw? Could they mirror an ally's looks as a sculpor might using Shape Water? Could it pass as a jelly dragonborn to tease the real one (for a sillier example)?

Comment: As they can wear any equipment, they will be able to form the protrusions needed to do so, like a chin-like bulge.  I think the rest of it is in the domain of the DMs interpretation.

Comment: @VictorB I imagine it the same way as they put clothing on those mannequins in clothes stores, it doesn’t have to fit super well, as long as it stays on that’s good enough

Comment: @VictorB The sallet helmet -- The rules definitely gloss over details like this.  Armor is just armor.  The basic rules just simplify the world of complexities like this for playability.